# Construct single InterpolatingFunction from a mathematical combination of other InterpolatingFunctions

Tags: functions, function-construction, simplifying-expressions, interpolation

Let's say I have an interpolated function `f`, like I might get as the solution to an `NDSolve`:

```
f[x_] = y[x] /. First[NDSolve[{y'[x] == Cos[x], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>][x]

Now suppose I define some convoluted function in terms of `f`:

```
g[x_] = f[x]^2 - 2 f[x]^4 + 3 x
```

> 3 x - 2 InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>][x]^4 + InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>][x]^2

This new function `g` preserves all the structure of how I constructed it, and in order to compute a value for, say, `g[0.5]`, it will perform the computation in terms of `f`.

This allows me to do algebraic things like

```
Simplify[g[x] / f[x]]
```

> (3 x) / InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>][x] + InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>][x] - 2 InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>][x]^3

which works because Mathematica is remembering the details of `g`'s construction in terms of `f`.

But for my own use case, once I've defined `g`, I no longer care at all about `f`. Is there a way to tell Mathematica to forget about all the complexity that is `g`'s definition with respect to `f`, and collapse `g` all into a single `InterpolatingFunction` that produces the same values?

Comment: I think that after defining `g` with `Set` (`=`, as you do), you can safely `Remove[f]` without affecting `g`.

Comment: That's true, but even in that case `g[x]` still produces a linear combination of three terms including several `InterpolatingFunction`s. But I don't care, in my mind `g` is just a function that takes a value of `x` between 0 and 1 and returns a particular value; I just want a single `InterpolatingFunction` object that does that exact job.

Comment: You could use `FunctionInterpolation` on the combined function, result will be a single interpolation function, though there's going to be some difference in result...

Answer (score 3):

You can augment your [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) call to output your desired interpolating function. For your example we could do:

```
{f, g} = NDSolveValue[
    {
    y'[x] == Cos[x], y[0] == 0,
    z'[x] == 2 y[x] y'[x] - 8 y[x]^3 y'[x] + 3, z[0] == 0
    },
    {y, z},
    {x, 0, 1}
];
```

Here's what `g` looks like:

```
g //OutputForm
```

> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]

Let's compare the two approaches:

```
Plot[f[x]^2 - 2 f[x]^4 + 3 x, {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

I think this is a better approach than using [`FunctionInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionInterpolation) to create a single [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction). [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) will adjust the step size so that both `f` and `g` are computed with the same precision and accuracy goals, while [`FunctionInterpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionInterpolation) can only use the accuracy/precision already present in `f`.